# Android fast pixel operations

Tags: android, image, loops, draw, pixel

I'm trying to write some code that let me draw an array of pixels to the screen. However I get very louzy performance on my Arm cortex A8 600mhz at 320x240 pixels.

Can someone explain to me where the bottleneck is and/or how to fix it? Changing the height and width barely helps too. I noticed similar behaviour with Swing in Java. I'm using code below:

```
package com.pixeldraw;


import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Debug;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.Window;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(new Panel(this));
        Debug.startMethodTracing("pixeldraw");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Debug.stopMethodTracing();
    }

    class Panel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
        private TutorialThread _thread;
        private Bitmap _buffer;
        private ArrayList<GraphicObject> _graphics = new ArrayList<GraphicObject>();
        private int width = 40;
        private int height = 40;
        public Panel(Context context) {
            super(context);
            getHolder().addCallback(this);
            _thread = new TutorialThread(getHolder(), this);
            setFocusable(true);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            synchronized (_thread.getSurfaceHolder()) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    GraphicObject graphic = new GraphicObject(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon));
                    graphic.getCoordinates().setX((int) event.getX() - graphic.getGraphic().getWidth() / 2);
                    graphic.getCoordinates().setY((int) event.getY() - graphic.getGraphic().getHeight() / 2);
                    _graphics.add(graphic);
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        long lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int CLOCKS_PER_SEC = 500;
        float timeCnt = 0;
        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
            width = getWidth()/2;
            height = getHeight()/2;

            long frameTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            // The elapsed seconds per frame will almost always be less than 1.0.
            float elapsedSeconds = (float)(frameTime - lastTime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

            int colors[] = new int[width*height];
            for (int x = 0; x<width ; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y<height ; y++){
                    int r = (int)(timeCnt/5*255);
                    int b = 0;
                    int g = 0;
                    int a = 255;
                    colors[x + y * width] = (a << 24) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
                }
            }
            for (int x = 0; x<10 ; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y<10; y++){
                    int r = 0;
                    int b = 255;
                    int g = 0;
                    int a = 255;
                    colors[(int)(timeCnt*32)+x + y * width] = (a << 24) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
                }
            }
            _buffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(colors, width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
            canvas.drawBitmap(_buffer, 0, 0, null);

            timeCnt += elapsedSeconds;
            if (timeCnt > 5) timeCnt = 0;
            // Update the last time counter so that we can use it next frame.
            lastTime = frameTime;

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            _thread.setRunning(true);
            _thread.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // simply copied from sample application LunarLander:
            // we have to tell thread to shut down & wait for it to finish, or else
            // it might touch the Surface after we return and explode
            boolean retry = true;
            _thread.setRunning(false);
            while (retry) {
                try {
                    _thread.join();
                    retry = false;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // we will try it again and again...
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class TutorialThread extends Thread {
        private SurfaceHolder _surfaceHolder;
        private Panel _panel;
        private boolean _run = false;

        public TutorialThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Panel panel) {
            _surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
            _panel = panel;
        }

        public void setRunning(boolean run) {
            _run = run;
        }

        public SurfaceHolder getSurfaceHolder() {
            return _surfaceHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Canvas c;
            while (_run) {
                c = null;
                try {
                    c = _surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                    synchronized (_surfaceHolder) {
                        _panel.onDraw(c);
                    }
                } finally {
                    // do this in a finally so that if an exception is thrown
                    // during the above, we don't leave the Surface in an
                    // inconsistent state
                    if (c != null) {
                        _surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class GraphicObject {
        /**
         * Contains the coordinates of the graphic.
         */
        public class Coordinates {
            private int _x = 100;
            private int _y = 0;

            public int getX() {
                return _x + _bitmap.getWidth() / 2;
            }

            public void setX(int value) {
                _x = value - _bitmap.getWidth() / 2;
            }

            public int getY() {
                return _y + _bitmap.getHeight() / 2;
            }

            public void setY(int value) {
                _y = value - _bitmap.getHeight() / 2;
            }

            public String toString() {
                return "Coordinates: (" + _x + "/" + _y + ")";
            }
        }

        private Bitmap _bitmap;
        private Coordinates _coordinates;

        public GraphicObject(Bitmap bitmap) {
            _bitmap = bitmap;
            _coordinates = new Coordinates();
        }

        public Bitmap getGraphic() {
            return _bitmap;
        }

        public Coordinates getCoordinates() {
            return _coordinates;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For these kind of operations you should also be looking into JNI, which allows you to use C, C++, or even native assembly (including ARM NEON where available), which can easily lead to a 10x speedup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From our company experience - pixel-by-pixel operations on near-full-screen bitmaps are extremely slow on android. One of the slowest operations we had on a custom animation of some sort was to make the background black by drawColor() which is exactly doing pixel-by-pixel filling of the screen...

So in your case probably the culprit is

```
   canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
```

But indeed - do profiling and you will know. With profiling you can drill down onDraw and see which method takes most time. This is how we found out.

Comment: It's hard to believe that the library would implement that function in such a way.  Why not just blt the whole thing over at once?

Comment: In older versions of android (read not 3.0+) there was no hardware integration for canvas operations.. You could get it for openGL but not for plain canvas operations... At least it looks like this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

1. Be precise... tell some numbers instead of **very louzy**
2. Move expensive operations outside of your drawing code

   int colors[] = new int[width*height];
   _buffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(colors, width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
3. Use profiling http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html

Comment: Thank you for you comment. I havent measured precisely, but I guess it was running at ~5fps. I will look into the profiling; very new to Android progging, so thanks for that.

Comment: Traceview tells me 93% of time is put into the contents of onDraw. Which is not helpful at all unfortunately..

Comment: I assume you talk about the "Inclusive" row... what does the Exclusive row tell you?